# MySQL SELECT * FROM 'table' syntax error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I understand that this should be a very simple thing to fix but I just can't find the syntax error. I am using a framework that substitutes the `?` character for the value that I pass into it so `"?" % "mytable"` -> `"'mytable'"`, very simple right?

I'm sending the string

`"select * from ? limit ?;" % ("assays", 10)`

and I'm getting the syntax error:

`"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''assays' limit 10' at line 1"`

I feel like I am missing something very simple.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @juergend it passes in `"assays"` to the first `?` and `10` into the second `?`

Answer (score 0):

You can't substitue table or column names with your framework - only values. The query compiles to

```
select * from 'assays' limit 10
```

But the quotes are wrong. Either remove them or use backticks. But the framework does that automatically I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your framework convert to "assays" to 'assays' and forward it to mysql. By the syntax error, it will send mysql like:

select * from 'assays' limit 1;

if you test on mysql, you will got the same error:

mysql>select * from 'test1' limit 1;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''test1' limit 1' at line 1
root@localhost [test]